# The costarico widget for yii2 take 404 error

Tags: yii2

The installation was successful.
The code was set up the same as in the documentation.
All is well, the picture is saved on the server but in the view it is not displayed:

```
             [
                 'attribute' => 'image',
                 'value' => "<img src = '{$img->getUrl()}'>",
             ]
```

Result:

```
<img src = '/19/images/image-by-item-and-alias?item=News1&dirtyAlias=b955bdfb6b-1.jpg'>
```

If i put:

```
             [
                 'attribute' => 'image',
                 'value' => "<img src = '{$img->getUrl()}'>",
                 'format' => 'html',
             ],
```

then do not show up - error 404

Comment: why you have space between each part of the value content and the  url .?. is a typo?

Comment: yeah that must be typo due to wrong code formating via snippet @scaisEdge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the author of the widget answered himself

https://github.com/CostaRico/yii2-images/issues/82